# How can I spot the "List index out of range" error in this code?

Tags: python

This is a hackerrank question.
I'm getting the error "list index out of range" in the line 'ea[i]+=1'

I don't understand how is the list index getting out of range. I'm a beginner.

```
ea = []
pair = []
ar = [1,1,2,3,2]
n =5
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        if ar[j]==ar[i]:
            ea[i]+=1
            if (ea[i]%2==0):
                pair[i]+=1        
return sum(pair)
```

Comment: `ea` is a empty list. So there are no items to index

Comment: What I wanted to do was define an empty array ea[] and then add to it. 

How could I do it in a better way?

Comment: Use `append`...

Comment: `ea.append(a[i])`. Same goes for the `pair` too.

Answer (score 0):

Your ea array is still empty, that means you don't have an element to be incremented.

ea = []
...
...
   ea[i]+=1 # At this point i=0, but you do not have any element at the array 'ea' so ea[0] 
     will be an error.